# How to Ioncube a symfony 5 project

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, ioncube

I'm trying to Ioncube my symfony 5 project and I'm facing some issues. I made a small sample project to illustrate my problem https://github.com/NichoSeb2/ioncube-symfony.

When I run a `composer install` I get a **Segmentation fault** error, I don't think it comes from the composer install itself but from the `php bin/console clear:cache` that composer do automatically after. If I run `php bin/console clear:cache` manually I get the same error.

I'm running the project inside docker, all explanation about how to run the project are on the [README.md](https://github.com/NichoSeb2/ioncube-symfony/blob/master/README.md) available in the github repo. Also included in the readme is the Ioncubed version of the **src/Service/TestIoncube.php** file.

If I replace the Ioncubed file with the original one I get no errors. I'm trying to Ioncube only the **src/Service** for now as my research showed that Ioncubing the entity and controller files can be more challenging.

I'm open to any idea of what I'm doing wrong or what I can change to get the sample project working with the Ioncubed file. Feel free to fork the repo, if you need more information don't hesitate, I really want this to work.

Comment: Just fyi: I have the same problem like you and contacted the Ioncube Support Team. At the moment they are investigating the issue and I am waiting for a response.
As soon as I know something new I'll let you now.

Comment: Sadly no, still waiting for a response.

Comment: I have same problem, Symfony5/php8.1/ioncube12. Can't figure out what's wrong